# why should we provide issuer, audience and key in both AddJwtBearer in ConfigureServices and while creating new JwtSecurityToken in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, jwt, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm new to **JWT Authentication**. I'm practicing it using this demo solution in my [repo](https://github.com/fingers10/JWTAuthentication). I understood how the code flows and able to make it work. But I have a question which keeps bothering me. Why should we provide key, issuer and audience at both places?

**`ConfigureServices` - `Startup`:**

```cs
services
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,

                ValidIssuer = "http://localhost:44348",
                ValidAudience = "http://localhost:44348",
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"))
            };
        });
```

**Token Creation Code in `AuthController`:**

```cs
private JwtSecurityToken GenerateToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
{
    var secretKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("superSecretKey@345"));
    var signinCredentials = new SigningCredentials(secretKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

    var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
        issuer: "http://localhost:44348",
        audience: "http://localhost:44348",
        claims: claims,
        expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
        signingCredentials: signinCredentials
    );
    return tokeOptions;
}
```

If we notice we can see the key, issuer and audience at both places. As far as I see we are doing because of configuration or setup? I think we should provide these configuration only at `ConfigureServices`.  Please correct me if I'm wrong and assist me with reasons for why we are doing it at two places.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why should we provide key, issuer and audience at both places?

You don't have to. Just inject the named `JwtBearerOptions` when you need. For example, change your `AuthController` to accept a `IOptionsSnapshot<JwtBearerOptions`:

```cs
public class AuthController : ControllerBase
{
    private static readonly Dictionary<string, string> _userTokens = new Dictionary<string, string> { { "abdul", null } };
    private readonly JwtBearerOptions jwtOpts;

    public AuthController(IOptionsSnapshot<JwtBearerOptions> jwtOpts)
    {
        this.jwtOpts = jwtOpts.Get(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme) ?? throw new Exception("JwtBearerOptions is null!");
    }

    private JwtSecurityToken GenerateToken(IEnumerable<Claim> claims)
    {
        var key = this.jwtOpts.TokenValidationParameters.IssuerSigningKey;
        var signCredentials = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

        var tokeOptions = new JwtSecurityToken(
            issuer: jwtOpts.TokenValidationParameters.ValidIssuer,
            audience: jwtOpts.TokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience,
            claims: claims,
            expires: DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1),
            signingCredentials: signCredentials
        );
        return tokeOptions;
    }

   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your time and the reply. Again this looks like we are adding these in `ConfigureServices` and using that in token creation `new JwtSecurityToken`. Instead of writing it we are using DI to get the options and assigning it. But my question is can these properties be ignored in token creation method since we already added them in `ConfigureServices`?

Comment: @fingers10 *can these properties be ignored in token creation method*:  The properties that you configured in ConfigureServices are used for Token Validation while the props you configured in CreateToken() are used for create tokens. They're totally two different things: Sometimes we don't have create our own tokens. We just validate tokens created by 3rd party. Anyway, token generation has no idea about the props used by validation service. But as a walkaround, you can wrap your own `TokenService` that takes those props automatically. And then inject the TokenService into your controller.